# Windows.Forms.Timer scope

Tags: .net, powershell

```
$timer = [Windows.Forms.Timer]::new()
$timer.Interval = 1000
$b=5
function tick {
    write-host ($b++)
}
$timer.add_tick({ tick })

$Form = [Windows.Forms.Form]::new()

$Timer.Start()
$Form.Showdialog()
```

Output always **5**. How to make timer be able to see vars from global scope?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the script scope modifier

```
$timer = [Windows.Forms.Timer]::new()
$timer.Interval = 1000
$script:b=5
function tick {
    write-host ($script:b++)
}
$timer.add_tick({ tick })

$Form = [Windows.Forms.Form]::new()

$Timer.Start()
$Form.Showdialog()
```

More information can be found here [about_scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7)